# how to run a java script from different aspx page

Tags: asp.net

HI I have a aspx page with a link . If i click that link i want the page to be redirected to another aspx page and execute the java script in it .. ...

plz some one help ... ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code below will redirect your page to another one :

```
<a href="anotherpage.aspx">Redirect</a>
```

and then after redirection occurs , use this technique :

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function init()
      {
         alert("Hello world");
      }
   </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
...
</body>
```

By the way, your question and its title don't match. I answered by your question.

**Edit :**

Since you look like a beginner, I would like to give you some more information about that :

`onload` event could seem cool but not as much cool as jQuery's `ready` method. Because html `onload` event will wait till every thing on the page is loaded but jQuery won't wait everything to be loaded. When DOM is ready, your code will be fired meanwhile the pictures and stuff may be still loading.